# Script samba password but securely

Tags: shell-script, security, password, samba

I want to script the addition on a samba user and the password.

I have seen solutions similar to the one here

[Piping password to smbpasswd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009/piping-password-to-smbpasswd)

```
echo -ne "$PASS\n$PASS\n" | smbpasswd -a -s $LOGIN
```

but the password is viewable to all that see the script. How can I use a hash and get that to be the password ?

Answer (score 5):

Provided that your smb.conf contains `passdb backend = tdbsam` you can export a file with encrypted passwords, on a system that was already setup, using:

```
sudo pdbedit -e smbpasswd:/tmp/smbpasswd
```

This will create `/tmp/smbpasswd` file with the user names and hashes. It is a text file that you can easily view and possibly delete the lines with users that you are not interested in.

The users can be imported back using the following command:

```
sudo pdbedit -i smbpasswd:/tmp/smbpasswd -e tdbsam:/var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb
```

The users in `/tmp/smbpasswd` will be added to the samba users database, or overwritten if they already exist.

`/var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb` is location of the file with samba users database in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Your script will have to be able to access the password. You can't use a hash of the password: if you did, the hash would *be* the password, since that would mean anyone with the hash could log in.

You should put the password in a separate file, and read it from your script. Take care to reproduce the password exactly (for example, don't use `echo -e "$PASS"` since that would interpret backslash escapes).

```
IFS= read -r password </somewhere/private/file.password
printf '%s\n%s\n' "$password" "$password" | smbpasswd -a -s "$LOGIN"
```

or

```
IFS= read -r password </somewhere/private/file.password
smbpasswd -a -s "$LOGIN" <<EOF
$password
$password
EOF
```

Arguments passed to external commands are visible to other processes while the command is running, so don't use the first solution if `printf` is an external command in your shell. Most current shells have `printf` as a builtin; use the `type` command to check, or the here document form.

Make sure that the file containing the password is readable only by the user that should be executing the script. Of course, any command running as that user will be able to read the script; if this is not desirable then you need to run the script as a different user (or use some other isolation mechanism, but a separate user is the easiest one to set up).